# GStreamer force GstBuffer deep copy

Tags: gstreamer

Is there a GStreamer element that will force a deep copy of a GstBuffer?

I need to create two video streams from a single v4l2src, applying different overlays to each.

**EDIT**

I am not using any of the GStreamer elements for the overlays. They are applied destructively to the GstBuffer in a pad probe.

Unless I am missing something, the code gsttee.c only pushes refs of the GstBuffer and does no copying.  Hence my question about triggering a deep copy of a GstBuffer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just use a `tee` element in the pipeline?

Comment: The tee forwards refs of the GstBuffers, it does not take a deep copy of the underlying GstMemory, so overlays I could not modify the underlying memory independently on each branch of the pipeline.

Comment: of course you can, e.g.:
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! queue ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! clockoverlay time-format="%D %H:%M:%S " ! autovideosink`.
This `tee`s a videotestsrc and apply a clockoverlay to one but not the other

Comment: Just getting back to this issue. See my edit. I am not using the off-the-shelf overlay elements. I suspect it is them that may be triggering a deep-copy as the tee just pushes refs. I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two video streams from a single v4l2src.

Here is an example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! tee name=t ! queue ! textoverlay text=hello ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! clockoverlay ! autovideosink
```

Gstreamer try to use zero-copy as often as possible for performance reasons. Gstreamer is trying to remove deepcopy everywhere!
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/events/gstreamer-conference/2017/Nicolas%20Dufresne%20-%20Zero-Copy%20Pipelines%20in%20GStreamer.pdf

Gstreamer has mecanisms:

1. zero-copy (parallel read of a single buffer)
2. copy-on-write (parallel read/write of a single buffer)
3. write-in-place (read & write the input buffer)

In the example above, clockoverlay et textoverlay are both elements that implicitly use write-in-place. tee and queue ensure we run them in parallel. So, we should read the same input and write separate outputs. We cannot have a zero-copy here because an overlay would overwrite the input of the other overlay. And worse: we should not read during writing!

So, in this example, we trigger 1 (or 2?) copy-on-write. When one of the overlays is locking for read/write, gstreamer detects we still have a ref (smartpointer) to this input (somewhere in the other queue). So it triggers a copy-on-write. gstreamer generate a deepcopy before processing the overlay.

If you still want to force a deepcopy for any reasons, I think you need to develop your own plugin.